# Cannot connect to Access using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to create a login page for my application. and when everything has finished and i want to login it always shows

**Error :**

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\Users\Gio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSS\CSS\bin\Debug'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

**Code :**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Login
    Dim path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
    Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub loginbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginbtn.Click
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSS\CSS\bin\Debug;")
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [User] WHERE [usernameField] = Username AND [passwordField] = Password", connection)

    Dim usernameparam As New OleDbParameter("Username", Me.usernamebox.Text)
    Dim passwordparam As New OleDbParameter("Password", Me.passwordbox.Text)

    command.Parameters.Add(usernameparam)
    command.Parameters.Add(passwordparam)
    command.Connection.Open()
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Succesful!")
        passwordbox.Text = ""
        Me.Hide()
        Main.Show()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password are incorrect!")
        passwordbox.Text = ""
    End If

    command.Connection.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub exitbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitbtn.Click
    Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: have you opened the access database exclusively using ms access?

Comment: how to check whether i have do that or not jade?

@jay thanks for editing. still new to this site :)

Comment: Oh sorry, you have't specified the ms access filename in your connection string.

Comment: ah yes you're right. but after ive specified it, the error change. it became Could not find file 'C:\Users\Gio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSS\CSS\bin\Debug\CSS.mdb'.

Comment: browse this 'C:\Users\Gio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSS\CSS\bin\Debug' using windows explorer and see if the CSS.mdb file is exists or else you need to copy the file in there.

Comment: yes it does exist there. but when i use explorer to do it, it cannot be found. why is it so?

Comment: Are you in debug mode or release mode or may be you have change the output directory? in your sample you are targeting debug folder.

Comment: yes i am targeting debug folder because my db is there. should i try to copy the db to another place and see if it works?

Comment: See my update answer the third sample.

Comment: it's working now jade. the problem lies in the PROVIDER for the access. it should be ACE because when i connect the app to my db it uses ACE. and also the format of file should be accdb. anw, thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: Well, your OS is 64 bit then... :)

Comment: ah yes it is! so 64 bit must use ACE instead of JET?

Comment: Microsoft dropped the support of Jet in all of its 64bit OS's since windows 7 and 2008 I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSS\CSS\bin\Debug;")
```

to

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSS\CSS\bin\Debug\YourMSAccessDB.mdb;")
```

or to load the db in your output directory

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=.\YourMSAccessDB.mdb;")
'".\" is equivalent to your output directory or where your application (exe file) is located.
```